# one image, another audio, don't get why similar structure doesn't apply the same in javascript.(source not changing)

Tags: javascript, html, variables, dom

Here is the first script, which worked just as fine as I imagined

```js
const maxNum = 4 //number of pages
pgNum = 1 //page number

chara = [{
    name: "A",
    aspect: "apple",
    src: "https://files.catbox.moe/r0k1oc.png",
  },

  {
    name: "B",
    aspect: "banana",
    src: "https://files.catbox.moe/82uq7t.png",
  },

  {
    name: "C",
    aspect: "creativity",
    src: "https://files.catbox.moe/eiv3z6.png",
  },

  {
    name: "D",
    aspect: "dog",
    src: "https://files.catbox.moe/stfuzk.png",
  },
]
charaImage = document.getElementById("charaImg");
charaImage.src = chara[pgNum - 1].src
document.getElementById("charaName").innerHTML = chara[pgNum - 1].name + ", the " + chara[pgNum - 1].aspect + " object";

//BUTTONS to increase and decrease pgNum, thus changing shown character name, image, description on the page

function previous() {
  if (pgNum > 1) {
    pgNum--
  } else {}
  charaImage = document.getElementById("charaImg");
  charaImage.src = chara[pgNum - 1].src
  document.getElementById("charaName").innerHTML = chara[pgNum - 1].name + ", the " + chara[pgNum - 1].aspect + " object";
} //the last 3 lines seem to work regardless of pgNum after pressing the button.

function next() {
  if (pgNum < maxNum) {
    pgNum++
  } else {}
  charaImage = document.getElementById("charaImg");
  charaImage.src = chara[pgNum - 1].src
  document.getElementById("charaName").innerHTML = chara[pgNum - 1].name + ", the " + chara[pgNum - 1].aspect + " object";
}
```

```html
<main>
  <h1 id="charaName"></h1>
  <p id="charaDes"></p>
  <button class="button" onclick="previous()">previous</button>
  <button class="button" onclick="next()">next</button>
  <img id="charaImg"></img>
</main>
```

But in the second script, it doesn't work as expected

```js
Num = 1
const maxNum = 2
document.getElementById("Num").innerHTML = Num
song = [{
    title: "A",
    src: "https://files.catbox.moe/c5zrzm.mp3"
  },
  {
    title: "B",
    src: "https://files.catbox.moe/jzu1ls.mp3"
  },
]
document.getElementById("musicTitle").innerHTML = song[Num - 1].title
music = document.getElementById("music");
music.src = song[Num - 1].src;

function next() {
  if (maxNum > Num) {
    Num++;
  } else {
    Num = 1;
  }
  music = document.getElementById("music")
  music.src = song[Num - 1].src //it doesn't seem to reflect the change despite its similarity of structure in the first script.
  document.getElementById("Num").innerHTML = Num
  document.getElementById("musicTitle").innerHTML = song[Num - 1].title;
}
```

```html
<h1 id="Num"></h1>
<h1 id="musicTitle"></h1>
<button onclick="next()">pipi</button>
<audio controls>
            <source id="music" type="audio/mpeg">
        </audio>
```

I see that both Num variable and song.title variable change and are applied properly on the page, but song.src doesn't change. I wonder what the problem is.

in both script I wanted image/audio shown in the page to change according to the pgNum/Num variable, which changes as button is clicked.
also, is there a way to avoid repeating these 3 lines 3 times in the first script?

```
charaImage = document.getElementById("charaImg");
charaImage.src = chara[pgNum-1].src
document.getElementById("charaName").innerHTML = chara[pgNum-1].name + ", the " + chara[pgNum-1].aspect + " object";
```

Comment: Start your num as `let num = 0;` to avoid the -1. Then have `const charaImage = document.getElementById("charaImg");` and make a function that can handle a directions - for example `const nav = (arr, direction) => num += dir; if (num < arr.length) num = 0; else if (num >= arr.length) num = arr.length-1; return arr[num] }'` - then you can start it with `let current = nav(chara,0)` to start and in your SINGLE click eventlistener (use delegation from the button container) you can have  `current = nav(chara, next ? 1 : -1);` which uses a ternary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It won't behave like image you must manually [load](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/load) them there are restriction on media elements (due to potential abuse or something)

```html
<html>

<h1 id="Num"></h1>
<h1 id="musicTitle"></h1>
<button onclick="next()">pipi</button>
<audio controls id="audio">
            <source id="music" type="audio/mpeg">
        </audio>


<script type="text/javascript">
Num = 1
const maxNum = 2
document.getElementById("Num").innerHTML = Num
song = [{
    title: "A",
    src: "https://files.catbox.moe/c5zrzm.mp3"
  },
  {
    title: "B",
    src: "https://files.catbox.moe/jzu1ls.mp3"
  },
]
document.getElementById("musicTitle").innerHTML = song[Num - 1].title
music = document.getElementById("music");
music.src = song[Num - 1].src;

function next() {
  if (maxNum > Num) {
    Num++;
  } else {
    Num = 1;
  }
  music = document.getElementById("music")
  music.src = song[Num - 1].src //it doesn't seem to reflect the change despite its similarity of structure in the first script.
  audio = document.getElementById("audio");
  audio.load()
  audio.play()
  document.getElementById("Num").innerHTML = Num
  document.getElementById("musicTitle").innerHTML = song[Num - 1].title;
}

</script>
</html>
```